# Laravel database FooSeeder still seeding when commented in the call function of DatabaseSeeder.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-seeding

All my seeders files are in `database/seeds/`:

```
$ ls -1 database/seeds/
BarSeeder.php
DatabaseSeeder.php
FooSeeder.php
UserSeeder.php
```

Even if I comment `FooSeeder` in the `call` function of `database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php`, it's still passed.

`database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call([
            UserSeeder::class,
            // FooSeeder::class,
            BarSeeder::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

So, what is the interest of using the `call` function ? Or did I miss something in my configuration ?

Comment: It should only run the seeders provided to the `call` method, could you add the output of `php artisan db:seed` to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have written your seeder, you may need to regenerate Composer's autoloader using the dump-autoload command:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

before running your seeder command.

check this
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/seeding

Comment: Indeed, I forgot that. Thanks!